# Can I access fields of an Object in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string str)` to translate a string into a .Net Object. The real type of this string can be multiple, and there's no other information to indicate the type of this string. But I can confirm that the string message is a derived class object of a common class like `Message`, and fields in `Message` can however tell the real type, `Message` has a field like `int type`. The string is `MessageA` or `MessageB` or whatever all with a different `type`.

If I translate it into an Object, I can saw in the visual studio debugger that this Object have exactly the fields described in the Json string. But I cant access these fields. And cast this Object into a Message will failed with a bad cast.

What I am doing now is first translate the string into a `Message` and to see the type, then I translate again. It's not preferred. So can I just translate it into something that I can read all of the data? Another option is Dictionary, but I have some numerical fields. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string str)`, when used on a JSON object, returns a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).  You can use this directly (e.g. use `DeserializeObject<JObject>` to explicitly type it), or as a `dynamic`, to access its properties, e.g.

```
var data = @"{""type"": 1, ""otherProperty"": ""Hello!""}";
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
if (obj.type == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.otherProperty); // prints Hello!
}
```

Also, you mention numeric fields as being a problem with working with a dictionary, but if you make it a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` you might find it easier to work with:

```
var data = @"{""type"": 2, ""otherProperty"": 5}";
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(data);
if (dict["type"] == 2)
{
    int i = (int)dict["otherProperty"]; // type is long, so cast is required if you want an int
    Console.WriteLine(i); // prints 5
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I didn't using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` before.